# Android ActionBar Styling not Rendering - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-actionbar

As the title states, while using Android Studio v1.0.2(And the latest Beta build as well) my custom ActionBar themes/styles aren't being applied in the preivew design pane despite them showing up in my app once I deploy. I am targeting Lollipop.

Is this something that's the result of how I have my styles configured, or an issue with the rendering?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme" >
...
</application>
```

Styles.xml (v21)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="ActionBarTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#FFF37022</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The desired effect is to turn the ActionBar background orange, and it is simply black in the preview pane despite being correct once deployed to a device.

Comment: I think you should use Appcompat instead of holo since you are targetting Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly now, you can specify the Theme to render with in the designer through a drop down menu next to the orientation modifier.